# Hibernate query not returning values from h2

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, h2

I am building a spring boot application with spring boot utilizing h2 and hibernate. I am trying a query and am not getting any results but when I do the same thing mysql I am getting a result. There no errors, I just get an empty result when I query my h2 database. Any idea's why I can yield results from one and not the other?

h2 config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:todo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password" />

        <!--Set the database dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!--Echo all executed SQL to stdout-->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!--Drop and re-create the database schema on startup-->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>

        <!--Name the annotated Entity classes -->
        <mapping class="com.todo.beans.User" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

MySQL config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!--Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todo</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!--Set the database dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!--Echo all executed SQL to stdout-->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!--Drop and re-create the database schema on startup-->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!--Name the annotated Entity classes -->
        <mapping class="com.todo.beans.User" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Query from DAO

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery("from User");

        return (List<User>) query.getResultList();
}
```

User Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    long id;
    String email;
    String password;
    Date createdAt;
    Date updatedAt;

    public User() {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

}
```

And both tables were set up in identical fashion

```
CREATE TABLE users(id int auto_increment primary key, email varchar(50), password varchar(50), createdat date, updatedat date);
```

Comment: what about are you getting, set up logging correctly ? Confirmed you have a valid db connection ?

Comment: @Kalkrin check your hibernate property hbm2ddl.auto=create so there is no data available in h2 database table, so change that into hbm2ddl.auto=create into hbm2ddl.auto=update

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Yes, I can see with <property name="show_sql">true</property> that it is querying the DB.

Comment: @Kalai - Unfortunately this did not make a difference.